# Null propagation operator in C++

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Has anyone implemented a null propagation operator in C++, similar to that used in functional languages?  I'm thinking of some clever template solution, possibly akin to the propagating behavior of operator->.

Let's suppose we have a chain of objects from a graph, like `foo->bar->baz` (sorry, Law of Demeter).  Suppose any one of these could be null, and should be tested before dereferencing.  Then the code suddenly becomes much more complicated:

```
if( !foo )
  return nullptr;
if( !foo->bar )
  return nullptr;
return foo->bar->baz;
```

I'd like to "factor out" the null checks with some kind of compact syntax like this:

```
foo?->bar?->baz   // imaginary null-propagation syntax
```

Now, of course it doesn't have to look like that, just be nearly as compact.  I suppose what's needed is a monad in C++, enabling the null test and a 'continuation'.  It would be great to avoid macros and lambdas, but that's probably not possible.  I could imagine overloading operator->() at each step and short-circuiting out if `this` was null.

But that's very intrusive.  An ideal solution would wrap each object in the chain.

Comment: Could you give an example of your operator in use?

Comment: Do you mean something like the `Maybe` monad in Haskell?

Comment: I think you should flesh up your 'question'; supposedly you're not just looking for "Yes, they have." If you want to ask something regarding your solution, then do so (but keep in mind there's also [codereview.se]).

Comment: @KennyTM Yes, like the Maybe monad.  Maybe my question requires a degree of language 'programmability' that just doesn't exist in C++.  But curious whether anyone has ever tried to cobble it together.

Comment: To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”
or if it is a rant disguised as a question: “______ sucks, am I right?”  http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @MooingDuck Not a rant, I love the language.  I think it's a specific, concrete question.

Comment: Additionally, I can't think of a way to "overloading operator->() at each step and short-circuiting out if this was null."

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9692630/implementing-haskells-maybe-monad-in-c11

Comment: @ScottJones: It sort of looks like a rant.  "I want C++ to have this particular feature"

Comment: Is `return foo && foo->bar ? foo->bar->baz : nullptr;` too much to type? Or, what if you have 100 levels of indirection? Well, then you probably should not be writing code.

Comment: @NateKohl Good find, thx

Comment: @VladLazarenko Ha - fair enough.  It's really just a bit of syntactic sugar for short chains.  I was also probing for a general reusable monadic pattern.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At this stage in your design it might be a radical departure, but perhaps consider using the [Null Object Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).  Then you don't need any null checks at all.

Comment: While I dislike the Null Object Pattern, that's probably the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

**tldr; I seriously doubt C++ can do that.**

Unfortunately, I don't believe it can be done (without the preprocessor).  My code always looks like

```
type function(type parent) {
    if (parent==nullptr || parent->child==nullptr)
        return null;
    //do stuff with parent->child->grandchild
}
```

In fact, you mention "overloading operator->() at each step and short-circuiting out if this was null.", but I don't think even *that* can be done (without the preprocessor).  If it were overloaded, you could make `operator->()` return null, but if `this` is `null` then calling `operator->()` was already undefined behavior.  And even if it weren't it probably would have already returned `null`.  You could make it throw an exception, but I think that path is far more complicated than the code I mention above.

Using the preprocessor, there might be something, but my first thoughts are ugly and dangerous

```
#define MAYBENULL1(X, Y) (X?(X->Y,nullptr)
#define MAYBENULL2(X, Y, Z) (X&&X->Y?X->Y->Z,nullptr)
#define MAYBENULL3(X, Y, Z, W) (X&&X->Y&&X->Y->Z?X->Y->Z->W,nullptr)

type function(type parent) {return MAYBENULL2(parent, child, grandchild);}
```

But you know someone will screw it up.

```
parent* get_next_parent();
type function() {return MAYBENULL1(get_next_parent(), child);}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful response.  I would have combined operator-> with something like the Null Object Pattern, to permit null objects in the chain.  But I suppose that just begs for a strict Null Object Pattern in the first place.

Comment: Could this be solved with lambdas? Untested: `#define MAYBE(X,Y) (([&]() { auto ptr = X; return ptr? ptr->Y : nullptr; })())`

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of null propagation in C#. The first is as you describe, where if `foo` is null, then return null, but if `foo` is not null, return `foo->bar`.

This isn't so convoluted or difficult to read already in C++.

```
return (foo) ? (foo->bar) ? foo->bar->baz : nullptr : nullptr;
```

It would appear that you cannot make a macro of it that would allow nesting the inline conditional the way I have it above.

```
#define Maybe(X, Y) (X)?X->Y:nullptr
// Attempted nested usage:
return Maybe(foo, Maybe(foo->bar, baz));
//     ^ VS2015 complains here saying "Expected a member name".
```

But given how wordy the macro is, even if it worked, I don't see how superior it would be to the inline conditional originally used.

There is a template solution, however, that even gets around the "double call" issue Mooing Duck pointed out in his answer.

```
template<typename T_Return, typename T_X, T_Return* T_X::*Y>
T_Return* Maybe(T_X* pX)
{
    return (pX) ? pX->*Y : nullptr;
}

//Usage:
// Type is required, so assume the struct Foo contains a Bar* and Bar contains a Baz*.
return Maybe<Baz, Bar, &Bar::baz>(Maybe<Bar, Foo, &Foo::bar(foo));
```

Of course while this meets the requirements, it's absurd and obtuse.

It is worth noting, however, that there is a second type of Null Propagation that is used for calling methods, meaning it needs no "else" case. It is the equivalent of:

```
// C# code here.
if(foo != null) { foo.Bar(); }
```

where in C# you can:

```
foo?.Bar()
```

This is a much easier feature to attempt to replicate using macros, and it "fits" better with normal syntax.

```
// C++ Null Propagation
#define Maybe(X) if (auto tempX = (X)) tempX

//Usage
Maybe(GetFoo())->Bar();

//Or for setting a variable:
Maybe(GetFoo()->bar = new Bar();
```

It works because it's not using the ?: shorthand, and instead is using a normal inline if statement.

Keep in mind, this only has the purpose of calling a method or setting a member.

If you're really persistent, though, you could do something like:

```
#define ReturnMaybe(X, Y) auto tempX = X; \
if (tempX != nullptr) \
{ \
    return tempX->Y; \
} \
else \
{ \
    return nullptr; \
} \
```

Which could be inlined to:

```
#define ReturnMaybe(X, Y) auto tempX = X; if(tempX) { return tempX->Y; }else{return nullptr;}

// Usage
Bar* GetBar()
{
    ReturnMaybe(GetFoo(), bar)
}
```

But this can't be chained and given the verbosity of just about every possibility (perhaps excepting the method-calling null propagation), you wouldn't exactly be solving any problems with any of the above solutions.

Edit - Made the templated answer *slightly* better.

Edit 2 - Was talking about this with coworkers and came up with some other options:

```
#define Maybe(X) (X==nullptr) ? nullptr : X
```

Usage:

```
return Maybe(foo)->bar;
```

Interestingly, this also works in the call-method case.

```
Maybe(foo)->Bar();
```

because what it expands out to is valid (albeit strange)

(foo == nullptr) ? nullptr : foo->Bar();

However, because you can't put a variable declaration in ?: shorthand, you can't protect from

```
return Maybe(get_next_parent())->child;
```

like Mooing Duck described, and would need to create a temporary yourself.