# how to avoid nullchecking on an Object which has relationship of composition

Tags: c++

First of all, I may wrote down English in wrong way because it's not first language. Feel sorry that.

Anyway, now I'm facing a problem of checking null so many times because what I'm willing to treat has many object as members of it.
let me show you an example.

```
// def:
class A {
public:
    B* getB() { return _b; }
    D* getD() { return _d; }

private:
    B* _b;  
};

class B {
public:
    C* getC() { return _c; } // Train Wreck. but it's needed on my frw...
   ...
};

// usg:
void foo(A* got)
{
    if(!got)
         return;
    B* b = got->getB();
    if(!b)
         return;
    C* c = b->getC();
    if(!c)
         return;
    // do something...
}
```

As you can see, there will be 3 lines on every each trying for accessing an member-data.
of course, I can put a macro to reduce those lines.

```
#define WRD_GET_3(expr, res, ret) \
        _TGet<decltype(expr)>::set(expr);\
        WRD_IS_NULL_3(_TGet<decltype(expr)>::get(), res, ret)
#define WRD_GET_2(expr, ret) WRD_GET_3(expr, WRD_SPACE, ret)
#define WRD_GET_1(expr)  WRD_GET_2(expr, WRD_SPACE)
#define WRD_GET(...)     WRD_OVERLOAD(WRD_GET, __VA_ARGS__)

#define WRD_IS_NULL_3(VALUE, RES, RET)  \
    if((VALUE).isNull()) {              \
        RES.warn(#VALUE);               \
        return RET;                     \
    }

template <typename T>
class _TGet {
public:
    static T& set(T& expr) { return *store() = &expr, get(); }
    static T& get() { return **store(); }
    static T** store() {
        static T* inner = 0;
        return &inner;
    }
};


void foo(A* got)
{
    if(!got) return;
    B* b = WRD_GET(got->getB())
    C* c = WRD_GET(b->getC())
    if(!c) return;

    // do something...
}
```

but, it still requires to put single line for accessing sub objs.
is there any way for doing like below?

```
void foo(A* got)
{
    C* c = got->getB()->getC();
    // if got or got->getB() is nullptr, c will got assigned to nullptr.
    // without exception.

    // do something...
}
```

heard about trainwreck anipatt. but want to persist current class designs.

Thanks in advance.

C.F, The first sol which I thought was putting "if stmt" on every getter method.

```
B* A::getB() {
    if(!this) return nullptr;
}
```

and It works in most usage, but not for virtual method. (of course, because of vtable).

EDIT:
sorry late for leaving msg for it.
even I use ref instead, there are still moments to check pointers what I hold.
and I made an idea for exception before, but afraid that it's too expensive to what I'm doing.
it may be best for using nullobject or my macro to solve.

Thank you for all your replies.

EDIT2:
For some reason, I got back into this task, and made a macro for what I want to do by reusing WRD_GET macro written at above.

```
#define _PUT(exp) _TGet<TypeTrait<decltype(exp)>::Org>::set(exp)
#define _GET(exp) _TGet<TypeTrait<decltype(exp)>::Org>::get()
#define _NULR(exp) nulr<TypeTrait<decltype(exp)>::Org>()
#define WRD_GET_1(e1) _PUT(e1)
#define WRD_GET_2(e1, e2) WRD_GET_1(e1).isNull() ? _NULR(e1.e2) : _PUT(e1.e2)
#define WRD_GET_3(e1, e2, e3) _PUT(e1).isNull() ? _NULR(e1.e2.e3) : (_PUT(e1.e2).isNull() ? _NULR(e1.e2.e3) : _PUT(e1.e2.e3))
#define WRD_GET_4(e1, e2, e3, e4) _PUT(e1).isNull() ? _NULR(e1.e2.e3.e4) : (_PUT(e1.e2).isNull() ? _NULR(e1.e2.e3.e4) : (_PUT(e1.e2.e3).isNull() ? _NULR(e1.e2.e3.e4) : _PUT(e1.e2.e3.e4)))
#define WRD_GET(...)            WRD_OVERLOAD(WRD_GET, __VA_ARGS__)
// yes... it's looks dumb.
```

usage

```
// as-is:
A* a = getA();
if(!a) return;
B* b = a.getB();
if(!b) return;
C* c = b.getC();
if(!c) return;

// to-be:
C* c = WRD_GET(getA(), getB(), getC()); // when I can recognize those commas into dots, It's pretty intuitive to me.
```

WRD_GET was already designed to avoid double call issue.
and this time, new WRD_GET macro was expanded to accept more than 1 access by getting hint to null propagation page you gave. Thank you.

anyway, even though it can avoid double call, it still requires to put and call additional g/setters and it may loss performance slightly. and codes can be improved by like FOR macro.
but, well, it's effective to in my env.

Comment: in your accessor methods, that return the pointer, throw a null pointer exception if the pointer is null. this will restrict your checking to the accessors, and any chained accessors that contain null pointers will throw, which you can then catch. It is probably better to return a reference than a pointer if you are going to throw. i.e. if the pointer is not null, return the dereference of that pointer otherwise throw.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Null propagation operator in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16269694/null-propagation-operator-in-c)

Comment: Why don't you just use references instead of pointers?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, `this` pointer cannot be null (it would be a reference if references had already existed when `this` was specified), so your if check is in vain:

```
B* A::getB()
{
    if(!this) return nullptr;
}
```

because accessing a non-static member function without real object is *undefined behaviour*:

```
A* a = nullptr;
a->getB();     // UB/illegal, whether you have the check inside getB or not!!!
```

If you want to avoid the checks for null pointers, use references:

```
foo(A& a)
{
   B& b = a.getB();
}
```

with

```
B& A::getB() { return *_b; }
// but you need to guarantee that _b is never a null pointer!
// or you make, if it is never changed anyway, _b a reference as well
```

If you cannot guarantee that _b exists, you alternatively could throw:

```
B& A::getB()
{
    if(_b)
        return *_b;
    throw std::runtime_error("illegal state");
}
```

This way, *if* the function returns, you are guaranteed to get a valid reference. This approach, though, forces you to catch the exception at some other point:

```
B* b = a.getB(); // assuming a being a reference already...
if(b)
{
    // use b
}
else
{
    // handle b not existing
}
```

vs.

```
try
{
    B& b = a.getB();
    // use b
}
catch(std::runtime_error const&)
{
    // handle b not existing
}
```

Sure, you don't need to place the try/catch around every single accessor, but can have the it around greater blocks:

```
try
{
    B& b = a.getB();
    C& c = b.getC();
    D& d = c.getD();
    // use d

    // even this is valid:
    D& dd = a.getB().getC().getD();
    // as the exception will prevent the next function calls in the chain
}
catch(std::runtime_error const&)
{
}
```

You could even let the exception propagate further and only catch it later (outside `foo).

At very least, you should catch it within main to assure destructors of objects on the stack being called (and thus make RAII working).

Be aware that with changed `foo` signature, you might need to check pointers outside foo:

```
A a;
foo(a); // fine; especially: no check that is not needed

A* p = ...;
if(p)        // needed unless that you are 100% sure that the pointer is valid
    foo(*p);
```

On some systems, though, exception handling can be expensive. If A not being able to provide a B object is a rather normal/usual situation, you might prefer to stay with pointers being checked explicitly.